# Создание кнопок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cоздать 3 кнопки с названиями 1, 2, 3, расположенные друг над другом.
Начальный вид:
1
2
3
Нажали на любую кнопку, меняется порядок на:
2
3
1
Нажали на любую кнопку, меняется порядок на:
3
1
2

Нажали на любую кнопку, меняется порядок на:
1
2
3
Код должен быть написан с ипользованием библиотеки jQuery.

Я не знаю как менять порядок. Подскажите пожалуста. Спасибо

Comment: Вставка Вашего кода в вопрос существенно помогла бы подсказать что.

Comment: Вам не надо менять порядок кнопок, вам надо поменять их содержимое, т.е. текст. 
А это сделать легко, условно вот так `$('.mybutton').text('Текст, для изменения');`

Comment: И какая логика смены позиции кнопок?

Comment: "Код должен быть написан с ипользованием библиотеки jQuery." - https://i.imgur.com/UIWTLVS.gif (сорри)

Comment: Менять порядок элементов можно с помощью этого метода: https://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('.test').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().append( $('.test')[0] );
});
```

```css
.mama {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test { margin: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mama">
  <button class="test">1</button>
  <button class="test">2</button>
  <button class="test">3</button>
</div>
```

Вот настолько просто)) `$(this)` - элемент, который запустил функцию (на который кликнули). Находим его родительский блок и пере-добавляем в него первую кнопку через append, и она оказывается в конце.

Перевод на JS:

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

for( let i = 0; i < test.length; i++ ){
  test[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let first = this.parentNode.children[0];
    this.parentNode.appendChild( first );
  });
}
```

```css
.mama {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test { margin: 3px; }
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <button class="test">1</button>
  <button class="test">2</button>
  <button class="test">3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: вот это бог jquery)))

Comment: Но это при условии, что задача будет именно такой как у автора.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let mas = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 1],
    [3, 1, 2]
  ],
  inc = 3;

$('button').click(butFunc);

function butFunc() {
  --inc == -1 ? inc = 2 : inc;
  $('button').each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).attr('title', `кнопка ${mas[inc][i]}`).text(mas[inc][i]);
  });
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button title="кнопка 1">1</button>
<button title="кнопка 2">2</button>
<button title="кнопка 3">3</button>
```

Как то так, это конкретно при ваших условиях 1,2,3; 2,3,1; 3,1,2. Если вы хотите генерировать произвольные числа то это другой вопрос.

Comment: `--inc == -1 ? inc = 2 : inc;` vs `inc = ( inc == 0 ) ? mas.length - 1  : inc - 1;` — а как легче читается?)

Comment: Думаю мой лучше)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.test').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().append( $('.test')[0] );
});
```

```css
.mama {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test { margin: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mama">
  <button class="test">1</button>
  <button class="test">2</button>
  <button class="test">3</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('button').click(butFunc);

function butFunc() {
  $('.mama').append($('button').first());
}
```

```css
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mama">
  <button title="кнопка 1">1</button>
  <button title="кнопка 2">2</button>
  <button title="кнопка 3">3</button>
</div>
```

Тогда ещё проще))

Answer (score -1):

Держите, пользуйтесь :)

```js
//Функция которая изменяет значения кнопок
function clickFunction() {
  if($('#firstButton').val() == "1") {
    $('#firstButton').val("2");
    $('#secondButton').val("3");
    $('#thirdButton').val("1");
  }
  else if($('#firstButton').val() == "2") {
    $('#firstButton').val("3");
    $('#secondButton').val("1");
    $('#thirdButton').val("2");
  }
  else if($('#firstButton').val() == "3") {
    $('#firstButton').val("1");
    $('#secondButton').val("2");
    $('#thirdButton').val("3");
  } 
 } 

// Вызов этой же функции
$('#firstButton').click(clickFunction);
$('#secondButton').click(clickFunction);
$('#thirdButton').click(clickFunction);
```

```html
<!-- Подключаем Jquery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Ваши кнопки -->
<input type="button" value="1" id="firstButton" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="2" id="secondButton" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="3" id="thirdButton" />
```

Comment: давайте на секунду представим, что таких кнопок 1 000 000, что будете делать?)

Comment: Ответ был дан отталкиваясь исключительно от содержания вопроса)